# Getting png crush error while creating ipa from unity editor in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am getting png crush error while creating ipa from unity editor. I did a sample game and want to run it on iPhone. So i opened build settings from unity editor and chooses iOS platform like below mentioned image.

[image: Image 1]

After selected iOS platform, It opens in Xcode 7 and i connected iPhone device. While Building this game am getting this error.

[image: Image 2]

I know why this png crush error (In Xcode we have more than one image with same name) occurred. Am using one plugin library for android os. On that library only i have that error image like below mentioned.

[image: Image 3]

My question is how to avoid android plugin libraries from Xcode. If we can't it means give some ideas to rectify this issue.

Note : I am new for unity game development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your second image, it says:

> iOSBuild/Libraries/Plugins/Android/google-play.....

This is a big sign that your Android plugin is being included in your final Xcode generated project. In your case, this problem is likely from the Google Play services plugin.

Go to *Plugins/Android/google-play-services...* and select each plugin file. On the **Plugin Inspector** tab, make sure that they are marked as **Android** and that **Any Platform** check box is unchecked. These files to select are usually `.aar` , `.jar` and `.so` files. Make sure to go inside every folder under the Android plugin folder and do this.

I will use the Google VR plugin I have demonstrate what you need to do:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Am doing this, let you know the status once i did this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Google Play Services plugin just for Android platform (and not for IOS):**

In the GooglePlayGames subdirectory in your project, just find all the occurrences of

```
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE)
```

or

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
```

and remove `UNITY_IPHONE` (i.e. `#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE` -> `#if UNITY_ANDROID`).

It will prevent Unity Post Processor to include Android Plugins in IOS build.